# `mrt add` throws unknown error when installing Atmosphere packages with Vagrant on Windows

Tags: meteor, vagrant, atmosphere, meteorite

Using Vagrant ssh on Windows 7, `mrt add scss` (as an example) displays the following in the console:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/MyMeteorApp$ mrt add scss
scss
    tag: https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss.git#v0.5.1.1

fs.js:730
  return binding.symlink(preprocessSymlinkDestination(destination, type),
                 ^
Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/vagrant/MyMeteorApp/packages/scss'
    at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:730:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/dependencies/package.js:129:10
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:75:15
    at ProxyWriter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib.souces/git.js:138:5)
    at DirWriter.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:323:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:313:32
    at endUtimes (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:239:48
    at setProps (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:296:5)
```

The same error is displayed when attempting to install any Atmosphere package the first time. The command does update `"packages"` in smart.json:

```
"packages": {
  "scss": {}
}
```

Whenever mrt is run again, the console displays `smart.json changed.. installing from smart.json` and hangs.
I did find the package at `/home/vagrant/.meteorite/packages/scss` but it is nowhere else.
My environment was set up using the [Vagrant Chef provisioning](https://github.com/shoebappa/vagrant-meteor-windows).  Node is version 0.10.10.  The OS is Ubuntu.  I have tried [reinstalling meteorite using the -H command](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite). 
 Any help is appreciated, I've been trying to get this to work for two days now.

Comment: What version of meteorite are you using ?

Comment: The meteorite version is 0.6.0

Comment: I think that's the problem. Meteorite 0.6.0 uses symlinks but Windows can't handle it. Try copying the sass folder into packages instead of making them symlinks

Comment: Worked for `scss`.  For some other packages I had to copy using cp -rL. Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind to vote as correct answer so other people can see it ?

Comment: For anyone else confused, the `mrt add` command fails *after* it's already been downloaded. You can install your package manually by running something like `vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/meteorapp$ cp -rL /home/vagrant/.meteorite/packages/bootstrap3-less/eprochasson/bootstrap3-less/f9d14d5d9325437997db0b407399a1cab710d83e/ packages/bootstrap3-less/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that's the problem. Meteorite 0.6.0 uses symlinks but Windows can't handle it. Try copying the sass folder into packages instead of making them symlinks.
Some packages you will need to copy with cp -rL